# Piecewise differential equation continuity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question doesn't have anything to do with solving the below problem, but I have listed it below for convinience.  The question states we have to solve

$y''+4y=g(x)$ with $g(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \sin x & 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      0 & x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}
   \end{cases}$

we are given an initial value of $y(0)=1, y'(0)=2$

My question is this: The solution says we must find a solution so that $y$ and $y'$ are continuous at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

My question is why do both $y$ and $y'$ have to be continuous? Why is it not enough to have continuity for only $y$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y'$ would not be continues at $x=\frac\pi2$, then its derivative, $y''$, would be infinite (or at least not well defined) at that point, which would not agree with the differential equation.